# All Tor nodes showing LOCATION as "Baghdad (Iraq) and Dhaka (Bangladesh) in Facebook

Tags: exit-policies

All Tor nodes showing LOCATION as Baghdad (Iraq) and Dhaka (Bangladesh) in Facebook.

For the last 5 days, I have tried all the Tor nodes to log into Facebook to see if there was some kind of leakage of real IP while using Facebook and I found that the Facebook's settings>security tab is showing only two locations:

1. Dhaka (Bangladesh) and
2. Baghdad (Iraq).

What is the real cause of this?

Another issue is that when we use proxies for simple (non-anonymous) surfing, one website with name "isisxxxx..." automatically tries to connect to the proxy server. (Note: ISIS is the terrorist organization which is eliminating the citizens of Iraq)

Is it all due to the Iraq War due to which USA is monitoring every traffic on Tor node, or Facebook supplying data of Tor users to NSA/USA by firstly sending the data to some location of Baghdad (Iraq) and Dhaka (B'desh)? It may be a trick being used by Facebook to separate our material/posts by categorizing by location.

Comment: It is interesting. I've noticed this myself. Everytime I check where I've been signed into, it appears as "Baghdad, Iraq". So I am lead to believe that there is a re-routing.

Comment: Although I am sure Tor node is from France
but Facebook says I am logged in from Baghdad !!! What could it be ??

Comment: This is likely a bug in Facebook software. Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I tested it with an Facebook account and indeed there were only logins from Baghdad. I asked the support and will write an answer/comment if I hear something.

Comment: @MercuryRising We do not need conjecture and speculation here (I've edited your comment). Please keep your comments on-topic and relevant to the discussion at hand (political discussion is almost certainly not on topic :) ). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Facebook says the location is based on an approximation, if you hover the mouse over the location you can see the IP Facebook bases its approximation on. Whois test of the IP shows it's not located in Baghdad/Iraq. So this, after all, may be a problem with Facebook handling Tor nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use FB via Tor, I strongly recommend you to use the onion version of FB through this link: https://facebookcorewwwi.onion which will not cause any location-error.

Comment: In my case ! The situation is ...
I am using Tor to access FB , from Dhaka , Bangladesh .
So for whatever reason FB showing my location is Dhaka , Bangladesh is not comfortable for me at all !!! This is the reason I'm using Tor to access FB .
So , if I use the onion link for FB , what will happen ?

Comment: When you use the Facebook hidden service, Facebook shows your location as London, England.